db to bigQuery from mongodb atlas
want to create a trigger in MongoDB Atlas that sends data directly to BigQuery via an HTTP request whenever a new document is added to my collection. I understand that I need to use JavaScript and do this with Node.js, but I'm not sure about the exact steps I need to take. I would like to get your ideas on how to approach this.
`const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { BigQuery } = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

const keyObject = {
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "your_project_id",
  "private_key_id": "your_private_key_id",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nYOUR_PRIVATE_KEY\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "your_service_account_email",
  "client_id": "your_client_id",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "your_client_x509_cert_url"
};

const bigquery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: keyObject.project_id,
  credentials: keyObject,
});

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/add-to-bigquery', async (req, res) => {
  const document = req.body;

  const datasetId = 'customer';
  const tableId = 'users';

  const rows = [
    {
      cartId: document._id,
      userId: document.userId,
      items: document.items,
      total: document.total,
      createdAt: document.createdAt
    },
  ];

  try {
    await bigquery
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .insert(rows);

    console.log(`Inserted ${rows.length} rows`);
    res.status(200).send('Data inserted');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error inserting rows:', error);
    res.status(500).send('Error inserting data');
  }
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});`


I wrote it this way, but it's not the right approach
